# To Sort the Array Independent to dependent values

Tags: php

```
$arr = array("a.test.com","a.b.test.com","b.test.com","a.a.b.test.com","c.test.com");
```

i need to sort the array as

```
$arr = array("a.a.b.test.com","a.b.test.com","b.test.com","c.test.com","a.test.com");
```

So that i can delete the indepentable domain to delete first

Can anyone Help???

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Can you explain the basis for your sort?

Comment: Couldn't you just explode each item by `.` and delete them in descending order of the number of items in the resulting arrays?

Comment: i cant able to delete since a.b.test.com is dependent to a.a.b.test.com, so first i need to delete a.a.b.test.com then a.b.test.com.. for this purpose i need

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton, no, i could not..

Comment: You have to provide any code showing your attempt to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **There is an example will help you.**

```
$arr = array("a.test.com","a.b.test.com","b.test.com","a.a.b.test.com","c.test.com");
print "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

function domainSort($a, $b) {
    list($aMailbox,$aDomain) = explode('.',$a);
    list($bMailbox,$bDomain) = explode('.',$b);

    if ($aDomain == $bDomain) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($aDomain < $bDomain) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($arr,'domainSort');
echo 'Sorted<br />';
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a.test.com
    [1] => a.b.test.com
    [2] => b.test.com
    [3] => a.a.b.test.com
    [4] => c.test.com
)
Sorted
Array
(
    [0] => a.a.b.test.com
    [1] => a.b.test.com
    [2] => c.test.com
    [3] => b.test.com
    [4] => a.test.com
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by the dot count:

```
$arr = array("a.test.com","a.b.test.com","b.test.com","a.a.b.test.com","c.test.com");

function cmp($a, $b) {
   $aDots = count(explode('.', $a);
   $bDots = count(explode('.', $b);

    // count dots
    if ($aDots > $bDots) {
       return 1;
    }
    else if ($aDots < $bDots) {
       return -1;
    }
    // if equal, do string compare
    else {
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    }
}

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnfZk/)

Comment: @user2324085 Then why does it have a JaveScript tag :p

Comment: @user2324085 It's pretty much the same concept. Modified the answer for PHP.